# Extending a function $\mu: \mathcal{C} \to [0, 1]$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is not closed under any operation, to a probability measure on a sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $\Omega$ is a set, $\mathcal{C} \subset 2^\Omega$ is a set of subsets of $\Omega$, with $\Omega \in \mathcal{C}$, but $\mathcal{C}$ **need not be closed under complementation, union, intersection, etc**.  $\mathcal{C}$ is just any arbitrary set of subsets of $\Omega$.

And suppose you are given a function, $\mu : \mathcal{C} \to [0, 1]$.

I am interested in the question: what properties must $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mu$ have in order for there to be some set of subsets $\mathcal{F} \subseteq 2^\Omega$, and some function $\nu : \mathcal{F} \to [0, 1]$ such that:

1. $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$
2. $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra
3. $\nu$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{F}$ (i.e., $\nu$ is normalised and countably additive)
4. For every $X \in \mathcal{C}$, $\nu(X) = \mu(X)$

Does anybody know of work which addresses this question?

---

Edit: By way of explanation, consider the following example: $\Omega = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$, $\mathcal{C} = \{ \varnothing, \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 3, 4 \}, \{1, 4\}, \{2, 3\}, \Omega  \}$, $\mu(\Omega) = 1$, $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$, $\mu(\{ 1, 2 \}) = \mu(\{ 3, 4\}) = 1/3$ while $\mu(\{ 1, 4\}) = \mu(\{ 2, 3 \}) = 1/4$.

$\mu$ is not extendible to a probability measure on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$.  $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ must include $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, and if the extension of $\mu$, $\nu$, is going to be probabilistic and agree with $\mu$, then we'll have to have $\nu(\{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}) = \nu(\{ 1, 2 \}) + \nu(\{ 3, 4 \}) = \mu(\{ 1, 2 \}) + \mu(\{ 3, 4 \}) = 2/3$.  And we'll also have to have $\nu(\{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}) = \nu(\{ 1, 4 \}) + \nu(\{ 2,3 \}) = \mu(\{ 1, 4 \}) + \mu(\{ 2,3 \}) = 1/2$.  So there is no probabilistic $\nu$ which extends $\mu$.

But $\mu$ is normalised, additive, and monotonic. That is, $\mu$ satisfies the following criteria:

- **Normalisation**: $\mu(\Omega) = 1$
- **Additivity** for every $X_1, X_2, \dots \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $\bigcup_i X_i \in \mathcal{C}$ and the $X_i$ are pairwise disjoint, $\mu(\bigcup_i X_i) = \sum_i \mu(X_i)$.
- **Monotonicity**: For every $X, Y \in \mathcal{C}$, if $X \subseteq Y$, then $\mu(X) \leq \mu(Y)$.

So being normalised, additive, and monotonic isn't sufficient for $\mu$ to be extendible to a probability measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$.  What *is* sufficient for $\mu$ to be extendible to a probability measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$?

Comment: You need to look at a book of basic Measure Theory. You can look for exmaple Real Analysis and Probability of R. M. Dudley from series Cambridge Studies in advanced mathematics

Comment: To be clear: I am familiar with the Carathéodory's extension theorem and related results (which is all I see being discussed in the Dudley).  These theorems allow you to extend a pre-measure on a semi-ring to a measure on the sigma-algebra generated by that semi-ring.   That's not what I'm asking about.  I'm asking about what properties $\mu: \mathcal{C} \to [0, 1]$ has to have in order for there to be some probabilistic extension of it, where $\mathcal{C}$ could fail to be a semi-ring.  In that case, extension theorems like Carathéodory's do not apply.

Comment: Ohh man, when $\mathcal{C}$ fails to be a semi-ring just use  the semi-ring generated by that class and done, even some book build a probability measure from any class using first the algebra generated by the class without ask anything from $\mathcal{C}$

Comment: I think maybe my question wasn't clear.  I've edited it to include an example which hopefully will make it clear what I am asking.

Comment: Now it is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

A well-known necessary and sufficient condition for extending to a *finitely additive* probability measure on $2^\Omega$ is de Finetti's criterion of coherence. In your case this would be: $\mu$ is coherent iff
$$\sup_{\omega \in \Omega} \sum_{j=1}^n c_j(1_{A_j}(\omega) - \mu(A_j)) \geq 0$$
for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $c_j \in \mathbb R$, and $A_j \in \mathcal C$.

You can interpret $c_j(1_{A_j} - \mu(A_j))$ as a bet on the event $A_j$ at stakes $c_j$ that is acceptable to $\mu$, where $\mu(A_j)$ is interpreted as the fair price for $A_j$. A coherent $\mu$, then, is one for which no finite collection of acceptable bets ensures a loss. You can easily verify that the $\mu$ in your example is not coherent.

Some additional, technical conditions must be met to secure countable additivity. See [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167715206003361).